# UISearchController as UITableViewHeader

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am having a view controller with a **UITableView** and a **Custom View**.The storyboard configuration is **Custom View** is alligned with *top, leading and trailing margin* of my view controller's main view.**Custom View** is having a *constant height*. **UITableView's** *top* is alligned with *bottom* of the **Custom View**. **UITableView's** *leading, trailing and bottom* is alligned with *leading, trailing and bottom* of main view. I am adding a **UISearchController's search bar** as **UITableView** header. This view controller is pushed on **UINavigationController Stack**. Now when user clicks on **search bar** navigation bar hides to make way for searchbar.But as **custom view** is above the **UITableView** it accomodates the position where **UISearchBar** should have been. I want to move **Custom View** out also and take the **UISearchBar** position which would have been in normal scenario without **Custom View** above. Help will be appreciated.[image: Initial Configuration]

[image: After search bar is clicked]

Answer (score 0):

Set the the IBOutlet for the Custom View's Height constraint and when user clicks on search bar then set e.g "customview.heightConstraint.constant = 0"
in search bar delegate method

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
customview.heightConstraint.constant = 0
}
```